# How to use Grunt while continually compressing css / javascript

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am just getting started with Grunt so please excuse a question which may be dumb:

If I am using cssmin or uglify or any other plugin that alters the appearance of my code:

How do I make it so that the reference in my `main.html` file stays consistent.  In other words, obviously I am going to develop with an uncompressed css file (let's call it `style.css`). If I am referencing that in my `main.html` as `<link rel=stylesheet src="main.css">` but grunt consistently minfies it to `main.min.css` it seems like everytime, after I run grunt, I am going to have to go into my `main.html` and change the link reference (which would be annoying because I have to update git each time too.

I  could configure cssmin to overwrite my `style.css` with the same file name but then it would be almost impossible for me to modify.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These plugins will help: [grunt-useref](https://github.com/pajtai/grunt-useref), [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml).

Comment: Ah yes, I tried to find something exactly like these.